# Short story about mercenaries fighting for corporations

Tags: story-identification

In the early 1990s I read a short story about a mercenary who contracted to fight for a corporation or nation. The fighting took place on a distant planet, the type of warfare and the weapons used were predetermined. In this story broad swords were the weapons used. The story follows one combatant who fights through out the day, near dusk he is wounded, using his med kit, he repairs the injury. As night falls, the dead rise and attack the mercenary. He fights through out he night, at dawn all the undead turn into flowers; flowers that cover the landscape.

I can not recall the title or author. I read this in either an anthology (1989, 90 or 91) or a Playboy short story.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've not read it in ages, but Larry Niven's *Night on Mispec Moor* describes a space traveller (I think) participating in a commercial feud of some kind. I clearly remember dying soldiers rising and him using a medical kit (an antibiotic spray, maybe?) to affect some of the zombies.

Comment: Thats it! thank you..

Comment: FWIW, I remember this being a very good spooky story. I will have to re-read it!